# NativeScript CLI fail when running "tns run ios"

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I'm practicing with this new programming framework called NativeScript, which allows creating native apps using JS. However, when I started working on the Hello World tutorial, I got this error:

https://gist.github.com/longpham91/d603c8fe7f6c6b06e86f

The error occurred when I tried running command "tns run ios" on Terminal, which basically allowed NativeScript to run HelloWorld app on my phone.

I also looked at the error log, and it seemed that the error might have something to do with my Xcode device settings, as explained here:

> Check dependencies Code Sign error: No code signing identities found:
>   No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)
>   matching the team ID “(null)” were found. CodeSign error: code signing
>   is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'

I'm not sure what this means, though.

Comment: I posted this thread on NativeScript's Google group and got some useful answers there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nativescript/ALCHIIkVXmg/PQnn66g86ZQJ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to figure this out after posting a thread on {N} Google group. Here's how:

1. Generate the Certificate and Provisioning Profile, following this tutorial: http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.no/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html
2. Go into the iOS section of your {N} project (under platforms/ios), and run the .xcodeproject file. You can also make a copy of this folder, to be sure that you don't accidentally change something in the source code.
3. When the Xcode project is opened, go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, and click on View Details.
4. Add the Provisioning Profile by clicking the + button.

That's all. Took me a while to figure this out since I'm not all that familiar with Xcode, but your project should run on your iOS device now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think the PATH variable "android / tools and android / platform-tools /" do not exist. You can use the android command in your shell?

Comment: FYI: If it's not a full answer, it might make a better comment.

Comment: I don't have an Android device so I can't confirm if running "tns run android" works or not.

Comment: Not "tns run android" only "android". Install android sdk, downoad API 17e 21. Install JDK 8 or later. Install Apache Ant 1.8 or later. Check your PATH variable for android (../tools and ../platform-tools), java and ant. You can use the command "java -version", "ant -v" and "android" to check it.

Comment: I see. I installed JDK 8 and Ant 1.9. The problem still persists.